# Android.view.View Error

Tags: java, android, arrays, view, return

I got this:

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.TextView;
```

...

```
   View android[]  = new View[6];
    android[0] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asd_frag, container, false);
    ((TextView) android[0].findViewById(R.id.textViewAsd01)).setText("Asd");
    ((TextView) android[0].findViewById(R.id.game_asd_name_one)).setText("hi");
```

and this

```
android[1] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qwe_frag, container, false);
((TextView) android[1].findViewById(R.id.textViewQwe01)).setText("qwe");
((TextView) android[1].findViewById(R.id.game_Qwe_name_two)).setText("bye");
return android;
```

When I try to return this array I get a strange message which says:

```
*Incompatible types

Required android.view.View

Found android.view.View[]*
```

I basically just want to give out my array.

So I clicked on the Android Studio hint and I got this strange error,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try `View[] android` instead of `View android[]` when you are defining the variable.

which makes it

```
View[] android  = new View[6];
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the incompatible types problem. You still return an array

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do more rather than just an "i got this:"

Comment: I just want to return my array

Answer (score 0):

`android` is an array of `View`.

```
*Incompatible types

Required android.view.View

Found android.view.View[]*
```

The function that you're working in has a return type of android.view.View, not an array of Views (`android.view.View[]`).

If this is not a overridden function that you have to match the definition, you can change to function definition to `android.view.View[]`.

Otherwise, you need to return an element of `android`, i.e. `android[0]`

Comment: Hm ok thank you, how do change the function definition to android.view.View[]